# How to give dynamics values for [routerLink] which it corresponds to values of an array?

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if, routerlink

I want to make a dynamic routing into my template. Values of routing come from an array which is iterated with ngFor. Also I want to make some transformations to this values which are of type string. 
Thanks

I tried to put values from an array but it gives me this error : 
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'items.label'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'items.label'

```
<li *ngFor = "let items of this.labelsMenu|async">
    <a[routerLink]="['items.label'] " href="#" >
</li>
```

Comment: Try removing the single quotes from `'items.label'`

Comment: Thank you, but how can I transfom the value of items.label to put it lowercase ?

Comment: I'd use a "pipe" which can transform each of your items. Take a look at [this](https://angular.io/api/common/LowerCasePipe) link.

Comment: Sorry , I used it but I writed it wrong . It works now !  Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

It should be without the quotes in **`'items.label'`**

```
<li *ngFor = "let items of this.labelsMenu|async">
    <a[routerLink]="[items.label] " href="#" >
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the single quotes

```
 <li *ngFor = "let items of this.labelsMenu|async">
        <a[routerLink]="[items.label]" href="#" >
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes and `href="#"`

```
<li *ngFor = "let items of this.labelsMenu|async">
    <a [routerLink]="['items.label']">
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove `single quotations`and `href='#'`. Hope you wanted to put `href` because of hover mouse pointer. For that you can add a style in your tag as given `style="cursor: pointer"`.

```
<li *ngFor = "let items of this.labelsMenu|async">
    <a[routerLink]="[items.label]" style="cursor: pointer">
</li>
```